# Simple ajax request not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to do a SIMPLE ajax request when the user changes a `select` element.

Everything is done via jquery .ajax. What currently happens(and works in everything except ie), is: the ajax loads a .html file, searches through it for the value submitted by the `select` element and replaces the information in `.results` what the selected element. Here is the code snippet. I think I've included everything relevant.

```
var results = $('.results');
var selector = $('.location-selector');

selector.change(function() {

    var selected = selector.val();
    var dealers = $('.results .dealer');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'dealers.html',
        success: function(data) {
            var test = '.' + selected;
            var search = $(data).filter(test);

            results.animate({
                opacity: '0'
            },
            500, function() {
                results.empty().append(search).animate({
                    opacity: '1'
                },
                500).show();
                $('.results p').linkify({
                    target: "_blank"
                });
                console.log('done');
            });
        },
        dataType: "text"
    });

});
```

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I even see the 'done' message in the console. I appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thank you!

Comment: Likely not related but shouldn't the opacity values be numbers vs. strings

Comment: Sometimes IE requires a dataType or even a contentType in my past experiences. Try adding one, the other, or both and seeing if that fixes it. Also, have you checked the network panel to see if the request is going out, and see if you're getting any errors or anything?

Comment: Thank you for this. I do have a dataType set and I tried setting a contentType earlier, but to no avail. I have checked my network panel and the console, and everything is going through. I even get the 'done' message, which is after all of the content should have loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

The html I was loading in had one div tag that wasn't closed. FML.